# .net AWS Lambda function cannot call custom web api endpoint in VPC

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that calls a c# Web Api endpoint. The function works correctly inside of Visual Studio and the endpoint performs as expected.  Once I publish the function to AWS I get timeouts (up to 59 seconds).

The function specifies the same VPC as the EC2 instance with the service and all subnets within that VPC. It also has the following role policies.

AWSLambdaFullAccess
 AmazonS3FullAccess
 AmazonSESFullAccess
 AmazonWorkMailFullAccess
 AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

Am I missing something else? The same setup (minus the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole policy) works in our test AWS environment.

Comment: Check the Security Group on your EC2 instance.

Comment: I did. I even opened all traffic on all ports

Comment: How are you specifying the EC2 endpoint? You would need to use the private IP of the EC2 server to access it from a Lambda function running in a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

While adding more detailed exception trapping, I added a cancellation token to the request and it started working. I also removed the VPC / Subnet information.

```
var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

response = await client.GetAsync($"api/aws/processEfmEmail?bucket={bucket}&key={key}", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```